# undeclared error on 'src' tag in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, windows-phone-8

i have this converter class :

```
    namespace WorkflowPhone8.Helpers_and_Extensions
{
    public class InboxItemValueConverters : IValueConverter 
    {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int urgency = (int)value;
            Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush();

            if (urgency == 0)
            {
                brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else if (urgency == 1)
            {
                brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            }
            else if (urgency == 2)
            {
                brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }

            return brush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value,  System.Type targetType,
                                  object parameter,  CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

and in my xaml i referenced this class as follows :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   <src:InboxItemValueConverters x:Key="converttocolor" />
```

as i build solution it says :

Error   1   'src' is an undeclared prefix. Line 71, position 6.

anyone knows why it does this?
or should i reference this another way?
using visual studio 2012, windows phone 8, silverlight, c#

thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the declaration of your "src:" tag look like in your .xaml?

Comment: in my question it states what my xaml looks like, im working from [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) and that says i should use src to call my class that i wrote to convert the data

Comment: It only specify how you declared your converter not your src-tag. You must declare your src-tag like the phone-tag is declared on top of the xaml.

Comment: my bad! i got it right with Karl's answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `src` as a namespace in your XAML. It would be something like this.

```
<Window xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WorkflowPhone8.Helpers_and_Extensions;assembly=WorkflowPhone8">
```

Though your `Window`-class (or `UserControl` for that matter if you are using this in a usercontrol) will have other namespaces as well so just append the correct namespace declaration to your root-element in your XAML.